# Python: multiprocessing pool memory leak

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I have an array of time courses that is 8640 x 400.
EDIT: The 0th dim are locations and the 1st dim is a time course for that loc.

I need to compute the cross spectral coherence for each point and these can all be done independently.

Thus I started trying to use the multiprocessing module:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np    
from matplotlib.mlab import cohere
from itertools import product    
from scipy.signal import detrend

# this is a module of classes that I wrote myself
from MyTools import SignalProcessingTools as sig

def compute_coherence(args):
    rowA = roi[args[0], :]
    rowB = roi[args[1], :]
    coh, _ =  cohere(rowA, rowB, NFFT=64, Fs=sample_rate, noverlap=32, sides='onesided')
    #TODO: use the freq return and only average the freq in particular range...

    return  np.sqrt(coh.mean())

### start here ###
# I detrend the data for linear features
roi = detrend(data=roi, axis=1, type='linear')
# and normalize it to std. Very simple method, uses x.std() in a loop 
roi = sig.normalize_std(roi)

roi = np.random.rand(8640, 386)# in reality this is a load from disk
length = roi.shape[0]
indices = np.arange(length)
# this gives me all combinations of indices i and j
# since I want the cross spectral coherence of the array
args = product(indices, indices) # note, args is an interator obj

pool = Pool(processes=20)
coh = pool.map(compute_coherence,  args)
```

This program uses over 20 GB and I don't see an obvious memory leak.
There's a lot of google returns on the topic but I don't really understand how to 
track this down.

EDIT:  Big mistake...the roi array is NOT 8640x8640x400 it is only 8640 x 400
Sorry... :| long day

Perhaps there's a mistake that I'm missing...?

Thanks for your thoughts in advance...

**[update]**
So after modifying the code and playing around with commenting out sections,
I believe that I have narrowed the memory problem down to the cohere() method.
Running the code and just returning arrays of zeros works fine.

Here's an updated version:

```
from os import path, getenv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import mlab
import scipy.signal as sig
from multiprocessing import Pool
from itertools import product
import Tools
from scipy.signal import detrend

from pympler import tracker
tr = tracker.SummaryTracker()
import gc


def call_back():
    gc.collect()

def call_compute(arg):
    start, stop = arg
    ind_pairs = indice_combos[start:stop]
    coh = np.zeros(len(ind_pairs), dtype=float)

    #tr.print_diff()

    for i, ind in enumerate(ind_pairs):
        row1 = ind[0]
        row2 = ind[1]

        mag, _ = mlab.cohere(roi[row1,:], roi[row2,:], NFFT=128, Fs=sample_rate, noverlap=64, sides='onesided')

        coh[i] = np.sqrt(mag.mean()) 
        #tr.print_diff()

    #tr.print_diff()    
    return coh

### start Here ###
imagetools = Tools.ImageTools()
sigtools = Tools.SignalProcess()

HOME = Tools.HOME
sample_rate = 1 / 1.65

mask_obj = imagetools.load_image(path.join(HOME, 'python_conn/Rat/Inputs/rat_gm_rs.nii.gz'))
mask_data = mask_obj.get_data()

rs_obj = imagetools.load_image(path.join(HOME, 'python_conn/Rat/Inputs/rs_4D.nii.gz'))
rs_data = rs_obj.get_data()

# logical index
ind = mask_data > 0 
roi = rs_data[ind, :]

# normalize with STD
roi = sigtools.normalize_nd(roi)
# detrend linear
roi = detrend(data=roi, axis=1, type='linear')
# filter
roi = sigtools.butter_bandpass(lowcut=0.002, highcut=0.1, sample_rate=sample_rate, data=roi, order=5)

# drop frames for steady state and filter noise
roi = roi[:, 16:] 

################
### testing ####
roi = roi[0:5000,:]
################
################

length = roi.shape[0]    

# setup up row and col vector of indices
indices = np.arange(length)
temp = product(indices, indices)# all possible combinations iterator
indice_combos = [ i for i in temp ] # make iterator into a list

num_cores = 10
chunk_size = len(indice_combos) / num_cores  # divdide the combo list for each core
grps = np.arange(0, len(indice_combos)+chunk_size, chunk_size)

#make the final list of args, where each item is a pair of stop and stop
args = [ [grps[i], grps[i+1]-1]  for i in range(0, len(grps)-1)]
args[-1][1] = args[-1][1] + 1

# deallocate some memory
grps = None

# Multi core
pool = Pool(num_cores)
coh = np.hstack(pool.map(call_compute, args, call_back()))

coh = coh.ravel()

out_path = path.join(HOME, 'python_conn/Rat/coh.npy')
np.save(out_path, coh)

map = np.zeros_like(mask_data)
map[ind] = coh.sum(0)

out_path = path.join(HOME, 'python_conn/Rat/coherence_map.nii.gz')
imagetools.save_new_image(map, out_path, rs_obj.coordmap)
```

**[update]**

It's not cohere's fault...my bad...I hope the developer doesn't see this... :|
I changed the code a lot. So I'm afraid this thread is prolly not valid anymore.

What helped:

## Only use iterators

## Send processes more than one pair of i,j to work on

There's a lot of overhead but the memory doesn't actually go up that much.
I feel like I've abused SO a little...but it's always hard to be precise here when you're learning something new...I'm surprised no one has hated on me yet. I'll post my own solution tomorrow.

Comment: You have almost 30 billion values in an array, no wonder this program uses that much memory.

Comment: Since you say you can process slices of this array independently, don't generate the whole array at once - do it sequentially. In fact, you can generate each slice within your paralleled evaluation independently, in place (as local variables) - you don't need to store them in memory (write them to file if you need to remember them).

Comment: @sashkello Sorry for dumb mistake... now there's only 75 million elements...not that bad.

Comment: Maybe it's just because you've simplified something, but your code doesn't depend on `roi`.  Is it that `rowA = roi[args[0]]`?

Comment: You also don't need to convert `t` to an array: `cohere` returns a tuple of two arrays, so just use `t, f = cohere(...)` or `t = cohere(...)[0]` if you don't need `f`.  Then, of course, `return  np.sqrt(t.mean())`  It's probably not the source of your problem, but it might be hurting a little because it forces a copy of all the results of `cohere`.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers don't add up.  As @sashkello already noted, you have an array with 29,859,840,000 elements.  Even if they took only 1 byte each, you'd be using 30 GB, not 20.  So what is it you're not revealing? ;-)

Later:  now 8640 * 400 = 3,456,000 - so where does "75 million elements" come from?  75 million would be close to 8640 * 8640.

In any case, two things to investigate:

1. How much memory does it consume if you don't invoke the multiprocessing machinery, and just do one chunk in the main program?
2. How big is the cross product (`args`)?  Since there still seems to be confusion over how big your array is, can't guess from here.

And another thing we need to know:  how many processes are in the pool?  Plain `Pool()` means "use all available" processors, but can't guess how many you have.  Of course memory use will go up for each one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions I will report findings tomorrow. The 75e6 is the resultant dim I've got that number stuck in my head.(1) I'll try and find out and (2) args is a list of every combination, the method name 'product' is misleading. That list is long and I made it an iterator, 8640^2 .

Comment: I'm going to try muppy from pympler and see if I can track down where the memory grows. I'm thinking to put the tracker call in the compute_coherence() method.

Comment: My boss is back and he thinks that multi threading is a better choice here. Plus, I should divide the work into chunks based on the number of cores, and have each core crank through it's allotted work. The way I've done it, there's a lot of overhead for spawning each process, just to work on one pair of indices from the data.

Comment: @wbg, a `Pool(20)` creates 20 worker processes total. The multiprocessing machinery uses pipes under the covers to give them work to do, but does *not* spawn yet another new process for each pair of indices. All the work is done by the original 20 processes.  If the overhead of the hidden pipe communication is a problem, then `pool.map(compute_coherence,  args, chunksize=len(args)//20)` gives each of the 20 processes 1/20th of the index pairs to do up front.  Whether threading is a better approach depends on a world of things I can't guess from here - worth a try, though ;-)

Comment: Thanks Tim. That explained chunk size. I'm doing that manually and will adopt chunk size once I find the source of the memory problem. Commenting out and will report back. Cheers.

Comment: My memory issue happens somewhere in the cohere() method. Just for fun, I made a call back method that calls g.collect() just to see if that will help. I suspect that I'll have to dig into cohere() more.

Comment: Ok I TAKE IT BACK,...not cohere's fault..I changed the code so much that this thread may not be valid anymore.

Comment: I agree ;-)  Please open a new one if there's more to be discussed.